# Deterministic and stochastic part of an equation

Tags: python, numpy, differential-equations, runge-kutta, stochastic

I'm on the lookout for a numerical method that can solve both a deterministic and stochastic equation. In the deterministic case, I know that a fourth order RK method is a valuable one, very effective. Unfortunately, there has not been applied to stochastic equations successfully (at least as far as I know).

Now what I want to know is if a numerical method that can solve both equations (roughly I mean, in comparison to the analytic solutions) exists and, in that case, what would be. A stochastic equation analytically solvable would be the Black-Scholes one, for instance.

Comment: Would it be possible to work on fitted / sliding averaged data instead of working with the equation itself?

Comment: You know already about Euler-Maruyama and Milstein's method?

Comment: Hi to both of you and thanks for commenting! Yes, I know both methods and I know that both are pretty useful when solving the Black Scholes eq in particular, but when I apply them to a deterministic equation the results leave much to be desired in comparison to RK. W.r.t the comment of Guimoute, I don't get the point. What do you mean?

Comment: Euler method is always good enough using the right timestep. In computational neuroscience is common to integrate both deterministic and stochastic equation using just the Euler method.

Answer (score 1):

There are methods for solving these kinds of equations in DifferentialEquations.jl. Stochastic differential equations are a form of mixed deterministic and stochastic equation and solving them is shown [in the SDE tutorial](http://diffeq.sciml.ai/latest/tutorials/sde_example.html). Mixing discrete stochasticity with deterministic equations [is shown in the jump equation tutorial](http://diffeq.sciml.ai/latest/tutorials/discrete_stochastic_example.html). While written naively in Julia, it is accessible in Python via the package [diffeqpy](https://github.com/JuliaDiffEq/diffeqpy). Notice that this has some [example stochastic differential equations in the README](https://github.com/JuliaDiffEq/diffeqpy#stochastic-differential-equation-sde-examples).